# How to use API key securely in flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, access-token

I had initially planned to include my OpenAI API key in my Flutter-based application. However, I recently learned that it's not advisable to store an API key in a client app since the app can be decompiled, allowing the key to be extracted.

Instead, it is recommended to store the API key on your server and have your server communicate with the external API. Your server can then relay the response to the client.

However, there is still a need to use server's API endpoint in Flutter app to facilitate communication with your server, that means attacker can still find out the server endpoint and ultimately use it to access OpenAI service

Comment: "ultimately use it to access OpenAI service" how?

Comment: Use something like FirebaseFuntions, add Authentication and/or AppCheck, even anonymous is better than nothing. Not having any authentication is a sure way to get banned by OpenAI. You have to be able to stop people that abuse your access.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an authentication feature on your Flutter app?

If so, then pass an access token from an authenticated front-end user to your server (for example, a Firebase idToken) and validate the token using middleware before granting access to the OpenAI route.

Comment: There is no authentication feature (login, register) in the app